# aws ec2 revoke-security-group-egress is giving errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

> aws ec2 revoke-security-group-egress --group-id sg-xxxxxxx --protocol
>   tcp --port 443 --cidr 175.41.128.0/18

Error:

> A client error (InvalidPermission.NotFound) occurred when calling the
>   RevokeSecurityGroupEgress operation: The specified rule does not exist
>   in this security group.

I have tried with --ip-permissions

> aws ec2 revoke-security-group-egress --group-id sg-wwwwwwww
>   --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 443, "ToPort": 443, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "175.41.128.0/18"}]}]'

Error:

> A client error (InvalidPermission.NotFound) occurred when calling the
>   RevokeSecurityGroupEgress operation: The specified rule does not exist
>   in this security group.

Comment: check you are in the right region or add `--region XXX` in your command

Comment: If you can set boto and run below command, what you get: `conn.get_all_security_groups()`

Comment: is there any cmd for inboud connection?

Answer (score 1):

The response means that the rule you're trying to remove is not present within the security group. Maybe it was already removed. I see you pasted the full error message in the comment above:

> The specified rule does not exist in this security group.

So try adding the rule, run the command to remove it, and see if you still get the same error.

Amazon's response error code is definitely confusing in this case, since it contains both "InvalidPermission" (which makes you think you're doing something wrong) and "NotFound". In this case, the "NotFound" is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you set AWS access key properly. when run aws cli command, always remember to add region, if not on default region.

```
--region eu-central-1
```

If you can set `boto`, and run below commands, what did you get?

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('<REPLACE_IT>')
conn.get_all_security_groups()
```

Comment: Yes,  i have added the region but still-------> Error:occurred when calling the RevokeSecurityGroupEgress operation: The specified rule does not exist in this security group.